# Application database/instance decomposintion

Tags: database, postgresql, scala, heroku, playframework-2.0

I'm designing a service that will serve some business entites. Logically it will be divided into two parts:

1. Frontend - bells and whistels like Wiki, Pricing, Landing Page, maybe account information (billing, account status, and so on).
2. Service itself, where business entity's empoyers will do theirs work.

It is play 2.x framework, planning to host in heroku.
It is not clear for now how to decompose intstances and DB stuff.

Should I decompose DB for clients: business entity - one database? Or should I store all data in one database, but add for all tables id of business entity that ownes some row? What issues (performance, administrative, scaling) may come up with this decision?

If I will choose to divide databases, how can I do this? For that I need to launch app instance with DB for client that instance belongs to. Thus we have non-uniform instances that can be obstacle for scaling. And as I know, heroku doesn't support non-uniform (web)instances.

Please help, i'm totally stucked here.

Expected stack:

- Scala
- Play 2.0
- Anorm
- JDBC
- PostgresSQL
- Heroku

All (except Scala, and may be Play 2.0) of this are interchangeable.

Comment: I'm not clear about the problem. You are writing an application, plan to have many clients, and you want to know whether or not to have them share one database or each client has their own database?

Comment: @ryan1234 Yes, that it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty classic problem. You have many clients and you wonder if you should create separate databases for each client - or if they should share a database.

I would recommend starting with one shared database and then use that until you out grow it. Think of some of the disadvantages to having each client with their own database instance:

1. Like you mention the schema management can be tough. You'd need to write tools to maintain all databases across all servers.
2. If you tell clients you have structured your system this way, some of them might push you to fork the database. In other words they might argue, "I have my own database! I want a new table just for me."
3. It's a bit harder to run queries across servers/databases. If you wanted to count how many items all clients have, you'd have to think about that a bit.

But if you want to start by sharding based on client (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)), you might consider:

1. As mentioned previously, you'll need some tools/scripts to launch a new database instance for a client. Often those tools will need to "seed" the database with configuration information - like populating a states table for addresses.
2. You'll want to have a tool to monitor/maintain the databases. Start one, stop another, see if one has high CPU usage etc.
3. You'll need some kind of system to aggregate statistics across all clients.
4. You'll need a tool to roll out schema changes and a plan on how you can gracefully upgrade the database while their web application is running.

Overall I would advise to start small and simple and only start worrying about scale when you get there.